# Facebook: Shared Page's Image Title Position

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I wonder is there any way to choose og:title text position in a facebook post when my web page is being shared? I want og:title text to be placed at center of a shared og:image instead of default left bottom corner. Here is an example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ijs9lc93hng5zds/og-exmaple-2.png

Comment: `to be placed at center of a shared og:image instead of default left bottom corner` - its not clear. Can you elaborate what and how you want to show!

Comment: @SahilMittal i am talking about something like this https://www.dropbox.com/sc/uts556kp41bq0no/k7MHUoQdYN

Comment: What's that- the yellow box? You're question is not clear at all, I dont think anybody here will be able to answer you! 
Also, what do you mean by `instead of default left bottom corner`

Comment: @SahilMittal updated example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ijs9lc93hng5zds/og-exmaple-2.png I hope everything is clear now

Comment: Oh. You cant do that! Its default by facebook, you cant change its position anywhere